# Packaging smart Vue components for npm

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to create a Vue plugin for a smart component contra a dumb component and package it for npm?

Here’s an example of a smart component, that uses a dumb component BaseButton.

```
<template>
  <div class="increment-button" v-on:click="increment">
<base-button>{{ number }} Increment</base-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Base Button is dumb
const BaseButton = {
  template: `<button><slot></slot></button>`
}

// Increment Button is smart
export default {
  name: 'IncrementButton',
  components: { BaseButton },
  data () {
return {
  number: 0
}
  },
  methods: {
increment () {
  this.number++
}
  }
}
</script>
```

When I install my Vue plugin and instantiate my smart component, Vue doesn't recognize `<base-button>` as a Vue component and render it even though, I'm registering it globally in the install method.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Best,
Bilal

Comment: Can you show how you're packaging it up and how you're registering `base-button` and give me a little idea of what you're trying to do? Are you trying to create a single file component so that this could be hosted in NPM and used anywhere?

Comment: Checkout `vue-hybrids`